# Who were the major manufacturers of the Apollo 11 rocket?

Tags: rockets, history, space-art, apollo-11, manufacturing

Organizing an exhibition around photographs from the 1969 launch and wanted to invite manufacturers.

Comment: I've added the `space-art` tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the major contractors for the Saturn V launcher and Apollo spacecraft:

- Saturn V [first stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-IC): Boeing
- Saturn V [second stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-II): North American Aviation (now part of Boeing)
- Saturn V [third stage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-IVB): Douglas (now part of... Boeing)
- Saturn V [instrument unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V_instrument_unit): IBM
- Saturn V engines: Rocketdyne (now Aerojet Rocketdyne)
- Apollo [CSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_command_and_service_module#Command_module_(CM)): North American Aviation
- Apollo [LM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Module): Grumman (now Northrop Grumman)
- Apollo SPS engine, RCS engines: Rocketdyne
- Apollo LM descent engine: TRW (now Northrop Grumman)
- Apollo LM ascent engine: Bell Aircraft (now Bell Helicopter)
- [Launch escape system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_escape_system): Lockheed (now Lockheed Martin)

There were no doubt many other contractors and subcontractors involved, but those are the major components of the launcher and spacecraft.

Comment: F-1 engine of first stage and J-2 engine of second and third: Rocketdyne

Comment: RCS thrusters for SM, LM and CM R4-D: Marquardt Corporation

Comment: ...which is also now Aerojet. (I think the CM used something other than R4D but whatever it is is probably also Aerojet by now.)

Comment: Apollo CSM and LM inertial navigation and guidance computers: MIT Instrumentation Laboratory, now Draper

Comment: I think the astronauts suits for EVA, the parachutes for landing, the radar for landing and moon orbit rendezvous were all essential parts of the mission. Also all electronics for telemetry and data transmission as well as voice communication.

Comment: I wonder how many of these places required employees to sign DND papers. Cant imagine ballistic manufactures allowed to go into detail about schematics.

Comment: Mostly covered by security classification if anything.