# Has the space industry ever had more manufacturing jobs than the aviation industry?

Tags: united-states, manufacturing, space-industry

**Was there ever any time when more persons were employed in the United States in the space industry (spacecraft), than the aviation industry (aircraft)?**  Please include manufacturing and support, but do not include end-user organizations (i.e. not airlines, military, or NASA).

(If it happened, my guess would be during the Apollo program.)

---

*Update:* Most companies -- including nearly all of the largest companies -- deal in both sectors rather than just one or the other.  The distinction within a company would need to be made by what is being sold.  I don't expect this question to easily be answered by public on-line information, but there may be enough information in the trade press to answer it.

It's possible that this question can be answered at a later date.

Comment: The two cross over sometimes, North American and Convair are two companies that made rockets or spacecraft and airplanes at the same time. How would one go about reconciling that?

Comment: @GdD before NewSpace, pretty much always crossed over.

Comment: Many companies producing parts for the Apollo program were producing aircrafts before, during and after the Apollo program. It would difficult to divide all their personel into spacecraft only, aircraft only and both aircraft and spacecrafts.

Comment: See the answer to [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33762/who-were-the-major-manufacturers-of-the-apollo-11-rocket) related question.

Comment: [Another](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36469/which-apollo-era-contractors-are-still-building-aerospace-components-today?rq=1) related question.